# Writing a Clojure function to sort a list of lists according to length frequency

Tags: list, function, clojure

I have written a Clojure function that can successfully sort a list of lists according to length frequency.

However, I don't like the way it is written. Does anyone have any suggestions for writing this in a different way?

```
(defn lfsort [n]
    (let [total (frequencies (map #(count %) n))]
      (sort #(< (total (count %1)) (total (count %2))) n)))

  (lfsort '((a b c) (d e) (f g h) (d e) (i j k l) (m n) (o)))
((i j k l) (o) (a b c) (f g h) (d e) (d e) (m n))
```

Kind Regards,
Ben.

Comment: What don't you like about how you wrote it? Is it too slow, or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn lfsort [coll]
  (sort-by (comp (frequencies (map count coll))
                 count)
           coll))
```

How do we get here from your solution? First, note that `(sort #(< (f %1) (f %2)) xs)` is just `(sort-by f xs)`. Then, since we only actually need to use the result of the `frequencies` call once, we can just inline it, and compose it with `count` to get our `sort-by` function.

You may or may not find this more readable than your posted solution; you can choose a middle ground by not inlining the `frequencies` call, but I think it's definitely better to use `sort-by` and `comp` than to spell out the `sort` lambda yourself.

Comment: Hi amalloy, perfect thankyou! It was the sort lambda that I didn't like.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is:

```
(defn lfsort [n]
  (->> n
       (group-by count)
       vals
       (sort-by count)
       (apply concat)))
```

For example,

```
(lfsort '((a b c) (d e) (f g h) (d e) (i j k l) (m n) (o)))
;((i j k l) (o) (a b c) (f g h) (d e) (d e) (m n))
```

I find this clearer. You may or may not.

Comment: Oddly enough, this solution has both the same number of tokens and the same number of parentheses as [`@amalloys's`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41045711/1562315)